# Negative number of active thread is displayed in Jmeter distributed mode

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

We have executed the script with 4k,5k, and 6k from 2 slaves(2k,2.5k,3k from each) and 1 master(receiving the response) slaves.

But the execution is stuck and has not been completed for the last 20-30 users. and also active thread count is showing in negative value.

[image]

So when this negative value is displayed in the active thread?
Why execution is getting stuck and not getting completed?

Also, we have sent 5k requests, and when we check in the HTML report, for some endpoints we observed that no of request is not sent matched as we sent.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to determine why execution is "stuck" is taking a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) and seeing what exactly threads are doing.

Among the possible reasons are:

1. Your application fails to respond and by default JMeter will wait for the response forever, it makes sense to define reasonable timeouts in [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) or equivalent configuration element.
2. You're violating [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) somehow. 3000 threads is quite high number for a single load generator so you need to properly tune JMeter for conducting such a load
3. JMeter doesn't have enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network or Disk, make sure it has sufficient amount of resources as it may cause false negative test results or who knows what else (i.e. negative number of active threads). If you don't have any better monitoring toolchain in place you can go for [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)